# Unable to access ENV in Rails worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to read an environment variable in my worker(also tried in rake tasks) like:

```
puts ENV('APILAYER_KEY')
```

but it throws the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `ENV' for #<ExchangeRateUpdater:0x0055c5a7a484f0>
```

As I can see `ENV` is supposed to be Ruby method and will be available everywhere. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/ENV.html

Has anyone seen this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the braces (as it's shown in the docs you've linked to):

```
ENV['APILAYER_KEY']
```

`ENV` is an object. The problem with your code is that Ruby treats it as if it was a method, and `"APILAYER_KEY"` as an argument passed to it.